# Cotton and synthetic clothes

Tags: everyday-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

Why do cotton clothes take a long time to dry as compared to synthetic clothes?
I read in a book that cotton fibres form hydrogen bonds with water molecules and thus, the rate of evaporation of water molecules is reduced in the case of cotton clothes. Is that so? How are the synthetic and cotton fibres different chemically? What is the structure of these two fibres like?

Comment: Do you have any particular synthetic fiber you are interested in? There are many synthetic fibers, so it is not a simple comparison of cotton v.s. all synthetic clothing.

Comment: Note that there are  many kinds of synthetic materials used in clothing: nylon, orlon, polyester, etc. Even different fabrications of these materials can have very different properties, and may contain additional synthetic materials like water repellents, i.e. in polyester fleeces and such.

Comment: Well, I don't think it is that much broad. I am just asking for the structure of the two fibres and why cotton takes more time to dry.